# Finding reference allele for mendelian randomisation

Tags: r, gwas

I am trying to perform an MR using summary statistics from this GWAS. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7026164/#MOESM1

Unfortunately, the summary stats in the supplemental only have an A1 allele and do not give an A2 reference allele or EAF and therefore I am unable to harmonise the data to my outcome data.

I am using MR package in R with code

```
x <- harmonise_data(
  exposure_dat =exposure_dat, 
  outcome_dat = outcome_dat_all, action = 1)
```

and i am getting the error "error in A2[to_swap] <- A1[to_swap] :
NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments"

I believe this is because it requires an A2 allele in the exposure dataset. Is there anyway I can perform the MR without it? Or alternatively, can anybody suggest how I can quickly find all of the reference alleles. There are around 400 SNPs so searching for them individually would not be ideal.

Thanks, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome. Just reminder that SO is not specific to bioinformatics, so lots of people won't know what you mean when you say 'GWAS' or 'MR' - so it's either best to spell it out or move it over to the bioinformatics sub stack.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can fetch `A2` from the column `uniqID` from the supplementary information. If they have not provided `EAF`, you can potentially use the 1000 Genomes data to calculate it.